# How to fix BingWebmaster Sitemap: Failed Status?

Tags: seo, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot

In Bing Webmaster, I recently resubmitted my sitemap after doing my regular changes. Every time, I try to resubmit, it shows "Failed" status as shown below.

[image: aads - bing webm fail sitemap]

Previously this used to not happen and the sitemap when I have resubmit in Google Search Console, it worked perfectly.

> Here are the use-cases I have run through for anyone who is trying to provide me an answer:
>
> 1. Checked if there are any errors with current sitemap with 10+ tools, everything validated it as fine.
> 2. I did my share of research on why Bing shows this "Failure" status, most probably because of a DNS error. In my case I have tested things and I seem not to find out the reason.

If anybody knows how to fix this or can suggest some troubleshooting steps, it would be a great help.

Comment: Deleted my answer (since it wasn't the answer) and taking things into the comments space instead. Okay, yes, saw your opening declaration when I loaded the page in DevTools. Honestly, everything looks good. What is the failure message when you hover over the orange triangle?

Comment: "Download of the sitemap or feed failed
We encountered an issue when we tried to download this sitemap. Please check the sitemap for errors and resubmit the sitemap."

Comment: There are no errors and I did google about possible fixes. General answer everybody has got from the Bing team is because of a DNS error but there are nothing such on my end.

Comment: You definitely got a puzzler there, @idk . I guess if you already reached out to Bing, and to your web hosting company (they might have dealt with this before), you can try one of the alternative paths to sitemap submission, such as using an HTTP request and seeing if what comes back is what's expected? https://www.bing.com/webmaster/help/how-to-submit-sitemaps-82a15bd4

Comment: I have reached out to Bing and am informed, their technical team is checking it. It is a problem on their end but on my end or related to hosting. I'll update myself with an answer as soon as they provide a fix to this.

Comment: Having this issue, too. Overnight stopped finding my sitemaps. Verified DNS settings are correct and fetched as BingBot without an issue.

Comment: @DanRyan I have updated with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes, when you resubmit or submit a sitemap using Bing Webmaster, you will get a temporary "Failed" status. When you encounter this issue, you can do the following:

- Check whether your sitemap is according to syntax and is available using the URL you stated.
- If the sitemap is good, then allow a few hours for BingBot to recrawl it and it will show the status as "Success" with the no. of discovered URLs
- If you're still facing the "Failed" status even after checking everything is correct on your end, contact Bing Webmaster Support to fix this issue as the solution might vary from time to time.

Notes: I faced this issue frequently and whenever it doesn't get fixed automatically, the Bing support would check and assist me.